# Navigation is not showing on home page and some category pages in magento2

Tags: menu, navigation, home-page

On the home page and some category page menu is not showing. If we go to the product detail page then it appears.

I checked some links and disabled fastly CDN as suggested but still no luck. Currently built in cache is enabled.

Can anyone suggest me please.

Comment: do you get any errors in browser console?

Comment: no errors in browser console,

Comment: Have you check magneto log files?

Comment: Fastly CDn was causing the problem.After disabling it menu started showing. Thanks